# help creating schema sql for hsqldb

Tags: schema, hsqldb

I am quite new to database programming and am trying to create a java program to access *hsqldb*(version2.2.5) using hibernate.I have 3 classes in my program which I mapped to 3 tables as given below.

I wanted to create a *one-to-one mapping* between SaleOrder and Bill.
Also, to create a schema for the db, I tried sql create statements.
The two tables SALEORDER and BILL have each other's id as a FK.To avoid dependency error between tables during create,I used *alter table add constraint* statements

Now,I want to use drop table statements at the beginning of script.I used the following

```
ALTER TABLE SALEORDER DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SO_BILL;
ALTER TABLE SALEORDER DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SO_BUYER;
ALTER TABLE BILL DROP CONSTRAINT FK_BILL_SO;
ALTER TABLE BILL DROP CONSTRAINT FK_BILL_BUYER;

DROP TABLE BUYER IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE SALEORDER IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE BILL IF EXISTS;
```

This however, causes problem when run for the first time(since the to be altered tables don't exist.).I could not find *'IF EXISTS'* clause for *ALTER TABLE* in hsqldb ..So what is the solution?Should I run the create table scripts alone the first time,and add the alter table,drop table statements shown above thereafter?That doesn't sound a clean way.

will be grateful for your suggestions,

sincerely,

Jim

The main schema script is

```
CREATE TABLE BUYER(
   BUYER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   NAME VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE SALEORDER(
   SALEORDER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   BUYER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
   BILL_ID BIGINT,

);

CREATE TABLE BILL(
  BILL_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  BUYER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  SALEORDER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,

    );
ALTER TABLE SALEORDER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SO_BILL FOREIGN KEY(BILL_ID) REFERENCES BILL(BILL_ID);
ALTER TABLE SALEORDER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SO_BUYER FOREIGN KEY(BUYER_ID) REFERENCES BUYER(BUYER_ID);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BILL_BUYER FOREIGN KEY(BUYER_ID) REFERENCES BUYER(BUYER_ID);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BILL_SO FOREIGN KEY(SALEORDER_ID) REFERENCES SALEORDER(SALEORDER_ID);
```

Also,I am using an ant target to create schema

```
<target name="createschema" description="execute schema">
            <sql
                    driver="${db.driver}"
                    url="${db.url}"
                    userid="${db.username}"
                    password="${db.password}"
                    print="yes"
                    src="${dir.schema}/${file.schema}"
                    caching="false"
                    showheaders="true"
                    >
                <classpath>
                    <path location="${dir.lib}/hsqldb.jar"/>
                </classpath>
            </sql>
        </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ALTER TABLE statements before dropping the tables.

Use the CASCADE keyword to force drop the foreign key constraints.

```
DROP TABLE BUYER IF EXISTS CASCADE
DROP TABLE SALEORDER IF EXISTS CASCADE
DROP TABLE BILL IF EXISTS CASCADE
```

Can also use

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE
```

Which drops all existing objects in the schema.

Comment: The first time it worked when no tables were .But when I tried it a second time,I am getting a nullpointer exception on DROP TABLE SALEORDER IF EXISTS CASCADE.

Comment: I used drop schema first and ran the sql .It worked.When I ran it once again,it threw nullpointer exception.here is the output of consecutive runs of the sql script http://pastebin.com/RgWUp0CY

Comment: I am creating the schema by using an ant target .I have added it to the post above

Comment: Regarding the schama design, it would be better not to use FK_SO_BILL. A bill depends on a sale order, but not the other ways around. The FK causes problems later when you try to insert a new bill.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There is an issue dropping circular foreign keys. This has now been fixed for the next HSQLDB point release